# Extracting multiple tables from webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract multiple tables from a webpage across many addresses that I have available, however when I run my script it seems to return some values for the last address in the loop.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

endpoint = 'https://parser-external.geo.moveaws.com/suggest'
params = {
    'input': '',
    'client_id': 'rdcV8',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Host': 'parser-external.geo.moveaws.com',
    'Origin': 'https://www.realtor.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'https://www.realtor.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36',
    
}

address = ['238 Lincoln St, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA',
 '101 Home Pl Ln, Hahnville, LA 70057, USA',
 '1250 Poydras St, New Orleans, LA 70113, USA',
 '1117 Broadway STE 401, Tacoma, WA 98402, USA',
 '2715 N Junett St, Tacoma, WA 98407, USA']

docs = []
for add in address:
    params['input'] = add
    
    r = requests.get(endpoint, params=params, headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    
    for i in range(9000):
        try:
            document = 'M'+data['autocomplete'][i].get('mpr_id')
            docs.append(document)
            print(document)
            break
        except:
            continue

property_info_url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/'

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/chromedriver/chromedriver',options=options)

test = ['M8021148490', 'M7965659502', 'M1205039451', 'M2499411953', 'M2907759924']

data={'first_table':[], 'second_table':[], 'third_table':[], 'fourth_table':[], 'fifth_table':[], 'sixth_table':[]}
for i in test:
    driver.get(property_info_url+i)
    try:
        data['first_table'].append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0])
        data['second_table'].append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1])
        data['third_table'].append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2])
        data['fourth_table'].append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[3])
        data['fifth_table'].append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[4])
        data['sixth_table'].append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[5])
        break
    except:
        continue
print(data)
```

I'm trying to get the requests to handle the webpage so that I can get access. The `document` is the page-link which I can access when appending it to the url to extract the information that I need. However, I do not get an output of all the results from the `pd.read_html()` part, it seems to cut off some of the results and only gives me values for a single link.

Comment: you code can not reproduce what you are describing.

Comment: secondly, it appears to detect bots. So possibly could be your issue.

Comment: @chitown88 it works on my end and I can produce an output, though it may be issues with the chrome driver you're having as my driver was specific to my case.

Comment: Nope. My driver works. And it returns that they are detecting a bot

Comment: Add: 'print(BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, ‘html.parser’).text)' right before your 'try'

Comment: Secondly it will not work on our end as test is not defined and addresses is also not defined.

Comment: @chitown88 Hi, you are right. There was so much text here it sort of threw me off. I have updated it and will add the print soon as I'm available

Comment: @chitown88 You're right about the bots after implementing your print statement. Any ideas on how to proceed?